# Format GridView Auto Generated Columns

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview, formatting

I am trying to format the width of my gridview columns dynamically for easy of use in editing and updating. Is it possible to have multiple column widths defined? Here is the code I am using to create the gridview...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Create a new table.
            DataTable taskTable = new DataTable("TaskList");

            // Create the columns.
            taskTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            taskTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            taskTable.Columns.Add("IsComplete", typeof(bool));

            //Add data to the new table. - could fill the table from database query if desired
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();
                //tableRow["Id"] = 0;
                tableRow["Description"] = "";
                tableRow["IsComplete"] = false;
                taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
            }


            //Persist the table in the Session object.
            Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

            //Bind data to the GridView control.
            BindData();
        }

    }
```

Is it possible to make a statement like:

```
taskTable.Column.Add("Id", typeof(int), width="200px");???
```

Comment: you just want to change width of column?

Comment: Yes, everything else is done in the html code of the gridview I just need to know how to set the column width for each individual column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must change AutoSizeColumnsMode set to fill then you can change the width of the column.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[columnName].AutoSizeMode= DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
dataGridView1.Columns[columnName].Width = columnWidth;
```